# How to access isValid variable from one.js to two.js in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am facing issue in below problem
Below is the code stored in 'one.js'

```
const One= (props) => {
  const [isValid, setIsValid]=useState(true);
  return(
      <div>Hello</div>
 );
}
export default One;
```

Below is the code stored in 'two.js'

```
import One from './one.js'; 
var Two=()=>{
    return(
        <div>Two</div>
    );
 }
 export default Two;
```

Comment: Very common question, you've got to change your thinking. State that is common between multiple components needs to belong in an ancestor component: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't access state of One component, because state is private to each component and this inaccessible
But you can create common parent component and use callback functions to change it's state and pass value to Two component as prop

Flow -  One -> CallbackFunction -> Parent -> Props -> Two

Also you can try to use useContext and share some data values between Two and One

Answer (score 0):

you can't access component's state from another component in reactjs

you have to learn and use redux for this goal or use hooks

but if you want to do it in pure reactjs you have to make one component parent of another component and send the state as props to child component

like this:

```
//one.jsx
class one extend React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            text: ""
        }
    }
    render(){
        return <Two props={this.state.text} />
}
```

and then use this in two.jsx component

```
class Two extend React.Component{
    render(){
        <div>{this.props.text}</div>
    }
}
```